# PGAdmin4 Browser: Autocomplete not working

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am using PGAdmin4 on my Firefox Browser(Mac). I am looking for auto-complete feature but could not get it work.

The [documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/1.x/query_tool.html) says that the shortcut for auto complete is "Ctrl+Space" but it does not work.

Has anyone figured out how to make it work?

Comment: still a problem on 4.2, even ctrl+space is unmapped for spotlight lancher.
BUT please recheck https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v3.4/macos/ ,  IT IS WORKING for me at this version.

Comment: Can you please reproduce this behavior with pgadmin4 3.5 version? https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v3.5/macos/

Comment: Facing same issue in above version too.

Comment: Same issue with pg 4.3

Answer (score 5):

It works if you deactivate the default MacOS shortcut for switching the input sources (keyboard layouts)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Clearly the PgAdmin guys aren't interested in supporting Mac users. "Only works if you disable standard features." OMG.

Answer (score 4):

###### fn+ctrl+space

works for me on my M1 mac